# error: conversion from 'main()::<lambda()>' to non-scalar type 'function<void()>' requested

Tags: c++, lambda, type-traits, invocable

In the following snippet I try to convert a lambda to my own function object, constraining it with a concept based on the invocable_r type trait. Yet gcc rejects it.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:47,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:47,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:47,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:47,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Fn,+typename+R,+typename...+Args%3E%0Aconcept+invocable_r+%3D+std::is_invocable_r%3CR,+Fn,+Args...%3E::value%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+R,+typename...+Args%3E%0Aclass+function%0A%7B%0A++++template+%3Cinvocable_r%3CR,+Args...%3E+Cb%3E%0A++++function(Cb+fn)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22Copy+constructor+invoked!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++function%3Cvoid()%3E+hello+%3D+%5B%5D()%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.804757760371345,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dgnu%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.19524223962866,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>


template <typename Fn, typename R, typename... Args>
concept invocable_r = std::is_invocable_r<R, Fn, Args...>::value;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class function
{
    template <invocable_r<R, Args...> Cb>
    function(Cb fn) {
        printf("Converting constructor invoked!\n");
    }

};

int main()
{
    function<void()> hello = [](){};
}
```

Error:

```
error: conversion from 'main()::<lambda()>' to non-scalar type 'function<void()>' requested
```

I can't seem to find the issue. What's wrong?

Comment: ot: its not a copy constructor.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Right,  a converting constructor is it?

Answer (score 3):

You defined template of `function` wrong. Your version accepts multiple arguments, when infarct you wish to have one argument of specific type.

You need to use template specialization. Also you have forgotten about `public:`:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>


template <typename Fn, typename R, typename... Args>
concept invocable_r = std::is_invocable_r<R, Fn, Args...>::value;

template <typename T>
class function;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class function<R(Args...)>
{
public:
    template <invocable_r<R, Args...> Cb>
    function(Cb fn) {
        printf("Copy constructor invoked!\n");
    }

};

int main()
{
    function<void()> hello = [](){};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xrvr3sMj3

Your version must be used this way:

```cpp
int main()
{
    function<void> hello = [](){};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xvGd1s4az

BTW there is [std::invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) concept, so you have introduced something what is already covered by std.

Comment: You're of course right. Interesting that you actually _need_ template specialization in this case

Comment: I wonder if this can be done with concepts only? Probably own concept is needed which will have template specialization anyway. IMO this is shortcoming of std concept library.

Comment: I _did_ in fact use a concept, check above ^^. Yes it's a shortcoming of the concepts library. Also, I had to switch around template parameters to make it fit